# kie-server installation for Tomcat container; Deployment of kie-server.war failed

Tags: tomcat, kie-server, drools-kie-server, drools-kie-workbench

I am trying to install kie-server for apache-tomcat-8.5.20. Tomcat is running but kie-workbench is not getting started. It throws the following error:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
25-Sep-2017 12:15:55.665 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start:
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/kie-server]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:988)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1860)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/transaction/TransactionManager
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at bitronix.tm.TransactionManagerServices.getTransactionManager(TransactionManagerServices.java:75)
        at bitronix.tm.integration.tomcat55.BTMLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent(BTMLifecycleListener.java:18)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:395)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:149)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.transaction.TransactionManager
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 26 more

25-Sep-2017 12:15:55.673 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Error deploying web application archive [C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.20\webapps\kie-server.war]
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/kie-server]]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:756)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:988)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1860)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

25-Sep-2017 12:15:55.682 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.20\webapps\kie-server.war] has finished in [86] ms
```

I have placed kie-server-6.3.0.Final-webc.war(which I have renamed to kie-server.war) in C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.20\webapps folder. The error occurred in deploying this web application archive. Any suggestion is welcome in regard to find the possible solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downgraded the version of web application archive from kie-server-6.3.0.Final-webc.war to kie-server-6.2.0.Final-webc.war, as mentioned in 19.2.1.1 section of official documentation at https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.2.0.Final/drools-docs/html/ch19.html#d0e19118 and the previous stack trace, is not occurring anymore.

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
25-Sep-2017 12:45:34.666 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.20\webapps\kie-server.war] has finished in [5,711] ms
25-Sep-2017 12:45:34.668 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.20\webapps\docs]
```

To solve `SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder"`, this link is very helpful: https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html